# Effeciently check if a list is full of zeros

Tags: python, list, numpy, optimization, signal-processing

I have a json packet with three channels coming in every second. Im doing filtering on these channels, but usally 2 of them are empty(just filled with zeros) and there is only one channel that are filled with values. The problem is that you can change which channel that transmits the data on an app. So in the beginning channel 1 can be filled with data, but then it can change to channel 2, then I also want to switch to filter channel 2 instead of channel 1. This has to happen efficently. These are some of the solutions I have tried now

```
class manage:
    self.channel_number = 1
    if np.any(json[self.channel_number]):
       self.channel_number = next_channel

    filtered = filter_signal(json[self.channel_number])
```

another method I tried is

just checking the max value (as this should never be 0) of the list and then do the same as above

```
class manage:
    self.channel_number = 1
    if max(json[self.channel_number]) == 0.0:
       self.channel_number = next_channel

    filtered = filter_signal(json[self.channel_number])
```

Now the checking for the max value is the fastest of the two. But doesnt seem effective to have this check every second as it is not very common to switch channel midway

the json data is setup like this:
json['data'] is a list of all the channels, so
getting channel 1 would be json['data'][0] etc.
The size of the data is around 200-400 and is on a list format.
Therefor will max be faster then np.max
Any tips to for the check if the channels is 0 or filled?

edit:
Example of list:
[0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.15, 0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.075, 0.075, 0.05, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.025, 0.1, 0.15, 0.175, 0.075, 0.05, 0.15, 0.35, -0.375, -0.325, -0.275, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

example empty list:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: Sample data would be useful for understanding and testing.

Comment: And in this case, as an exception, I mean JSON sample data. Usually JSON is not the actual problem/question and shouldn't be included, but in this case, you might get away with analyzing the JSON directly and then parsing only the needed part.

Comment: added an example list, its nothing special. The reason for the json is that there is alot more data that get sent, so this is just a part of it. And everything is getting parsed anyway. If I understood your question correctly

Comment: @Chris I highly doubt `np.any` will ever become faster. But feel free to suggest a size for me to check :-)

Comment: the test seems to show that the default python max and any is fastest. numpy was significantly slower. I think mCoding have a youtube video where he tests this but not sure and wasnt able to find it now.

Comment: @KellyBundy even at 4million?  I had ran the same tests prior to posting the comment an d noticed np performance was static while the others increased

Comment: @Chris Yes. Their lists have length 201, so I multiplied them with 20000. Then on the "full" list, `np.any` took over a million times longer than `any`. On the "empty" list, it took over three times longer than `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For analyzing a single already parsed list, simply using `any` might be best. Benchmarks with your full/empty sample lists:

```
 9061 ns  np.any(full)
 3468 ns  max(full)
  427 ns  any(x != 0 for x in full)
   80 ns  any(full)

 9019 ns  np.any(empty)
 3604 ns  max(empty)
14775 ns  any(x != 0 for x in empty)
 1668 ns  any(empty)
```

But like I said, maybe you could check the JSON already and then only parse the relevant part/channel. Benchmarks for some ideas:

```
   31 ns  '5' in full_json
   29 ns  full_json == empty_json_for_comparison
   82 ns  len(full_json) == empty_json_length

   41 ns  '5' in empty_json
   50 ns  empty_json == empty_json_for_comparison
   80 ns  len(empty_json) == empty_json_length
```

Or perhaps you could `zip` the lists and check them in parallel, so you don't have to check the empty lists entirely.

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VjtasIwFP2fp7gbSJpRXavImNAnGSKdxq3DpKGJUBl7dpePqq3WzYmywdIf57b3nOTmpk28RqzUa84H6/W8yBmojNFMQcZEXigoqKCpQkhStRSQAMYYVRRfMrGCVAIXaL5cLDT7FPWi/jCE08wxfDhuYguu/Z45hq5hv3Z/immL0DKqtrS@gG676tDdPam7n8PxSA1m33mW6JL21NgH5OXiXimda87K@e/yCp/cL0zzt@luRllb4I1do7HMHTNwfQ0eKlv13a@e@xZj9xC3v6avYIwoE2pV7aWX3wA8ePDw12BsC6jJm8y5qbF8GeXLKF9G@TLKl1Fnl1HY1VGNLdX/0njw8A@qqfrin8zzYjLNmUiLzO0FO@5pNOrGY4f1JgvKX9SrluqbYOcnyJx@oWk@o9L8QUOgL8xFL@Wr4L2UHwSHzsfSsukwihJuEohAjwdKyDgcCOqOWzzEG5ENflv5tw5I6qnspblRmwS2LcheE5emlo4RsqOSJiI2pSgOAVslHtmODD0xbJHyFxoMiHNvKDMlhrVTs6PMZanEmp6WslQFpUxKSRoqvmTPtNC6OIqiBqO0k2U8cAeRgeknBHsaGVatEmcIgfvK0@hAFBlXAe4MZ8AlYOhAoOAOYvpIQjus3UiclKzXnw)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = '''
import numpy as np
full = [0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.15, 0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.075, 0.075, 0.05, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.025, 0.1, 0.15, 0.175, 0.075, 0.05, 0.15, 0.35, -0.375, -0.325, -0.275, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
empty = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
full_json = '[0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.15, 0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.075, 0.075, 0.05, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.05, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.0, -0.025, 0.0, 0.025, 0.1, 0.15, 0.175, 0.075, 0.05, 0.15, 0.35, -0.375, -0.325, -0.275, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, -0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
empty_json = '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
empty_json_for_comparison = empty_json[::-1][::-1]
empty_json_length = len(empty_json)
'''

codes = [
    'np.any({xs})',
    'max({xs})',
    'any(x != 0 for x in {xs})',
    'any({xs})',
    "'5' in {xs}_json",
    "{xs}_json == empty_json_for_comparison",
    "len({xs}_json) == empty_json_length",
]

for xs in 'full', 'empty':
    for _ in range(3):
        for code in codes:
            code = code.format(xs=xs)
            number = 1000
            t = min(repeat(code, setup, number=number)) / number
            print('%5d ns ' % (t * 1e9), code)
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to explicitly compare with `0` rather than treating the elements as booleans.

```
any(x != 0 for x in json[self.channel_number])
```

Comment: I doubt it. Probably `any(json[self.channel_number])` is significantly faster.

Comment: The OP already tried that (except they used `np.any()`).

Comment: Looks like you made it [as slow as possible](https://tio.run/##hVDLasMwELzrK6aHIMmIIOMeSsB/kVsIwW3kVgc9kGVQvt7xWqVND6F7kua17MRb/gq@e4tpWcYUHLJ1xmZYF0PKSCaaITM2mTxH9OCcszKtj@akz02rtVZoGaHsI1wNMSeGdfjgb6LgpYfGGBIKrEeZJFeP9DPmmGbzSMKOqGH/y/6u@M11Q/n@nhkj04VMafCfRnTysIkIpjuI2e6pME1eT3PWi9qIIFZhq0XBz@7dpJ7qkPLHEZP1WfDd674d4SZw7CAyGrSmk2rLr@IqlMtyBw) :-P